# How to disable anti-aliasing in the background images

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

This is pretty straightforward: I'm using pixel art as background image and I don't want it to anti-alias like it is right now:

[image]

Comment: If your original image is not a vector format but a jpg or a tiff , I am afraid it's the quality and the way the image is that affects the outcome. You may have to create a higher resolution version by tracing the jpg on a photo editing or illustration software.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your interpolation type to **Closest**:

[image]

This also works with Materials Too.